# lazyLoadXT Background images add-on with multiple sources

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-lazyload

I'm using Jquery lazyLoadXT to load background images of specific DIV. I'm trying to have different SRC atributes, so it should load smaller images for mobile devices.

This is the markup:

```
<div class="img-container" data-bg="img/intro-00.jpg" data-bg-sm="img/intro-00-sm.jpg"></div>

<script>
    $.extend($.lazyLoadXT, {
      srcAttr: 'data-bkg-sm'
    });
</script>
```

Lazyload is working, but still loads the default image (data-bg). Is there an conflict between "srcAttr" and the background images add-on? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/tree/gh-pages/plugins/bgset

Comment: Thank you Alexander! I'll check into it.